# How to Invoke Chrome Browser to client machine when Server is located elsewhere running Selenium Application

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Selenium application which is running in a webhost and I want to invoke chrome browser in my local machine but every time I am getting below error

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally. 

(session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist) 
(The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) 
(Driver info: chromedriver=121.0.6167.85 (3f98d690ad7e59242ef110144c757b2ac4eef1a2-refs/branch-heads/6167@{#1539}),platform=Linux 5.15.0-92-generic x86_64) 
(WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) 
Command duration or timeout: 5.03 seconds Build info: version: 
'2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', 
time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09' System info: host: 'localhost', ip: 
'127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: 
'5.15.0-92-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_392' Driver info: 
org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

Application is invoking Chrome driver installed in the server and so no browser popup in my local machine.
Please guide to solve the issue.

Application which is running in server should invoke chrome browser in the client machine

Comment: You'd need to setup your client machine as a grid to launch it from the server.   (Basically you'd need to make it a server to expose it's IP to the internet.... at that point your client machine would then run the driver as a remote webdriver controlled by the server's code.)  What's the use-case?  (what are you trying to do in a broader sense?)